# Telerik RadDatePicker breaking on partial update

Tags: c#, telerik

I have searched and searched to no avail.  I am using

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="prev_startempdate" runat="server" Width="115px">
<Calendar ShowRowHeaders="False" Width="160" />
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

When my page first loads it works fine, but when the page does a partial update to show more fields depending on a certain answer the calendar popups stop working.  If I manually type a date, they get removed from the box as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the raddatepicker is in update panel...

Comment: Also  block of code of radpicker

Comment: Any JavaScript errors?  that is the typical culprit.  I have a RadDatePicker that works fine with async postbacks?  Also, you are using RadUpdatePanel or RadAjaxManager for posting back?

Comment: It ended up being javascript related.  Thank you for your help.